# Angular injector code sample from docs does not work

Tags: angularjs

I was trying to understand DI in Angular and i found this code sample for angular.injector in official API docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.injector

```
var $div = $('<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">{{content.label}}</div>');
$(document.body).append($div);

angular.element(document).injector().invoke(function($compile) {
  var scope = angular.element($div).scope();
  $compile($div)(scope);

  scope.digest$ // Added to work but WHY???
});
```

I've been trying to make it work but cannot - it looks like DIV is not compiled at all. After I added explicit digest$() it works. The question is why I have to call $digest? this is bootstrapped Angular app and I am not "outside" it eg. not in DOM event handler 
here is JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yoorek/w99EX/

Comment: Okey, I got it - After $compile I need to call scope.$digest() manually... don't understand why?

Comment: what version of the docs are you reading? notice that jsFiddle version is old  1.2.1.